# import m2m relation in django-import-export

Tags: python, django

use application django-import-export. Here is an example configuration for one of the models:

```
class ImportExportAdsTypeResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = AdType
        import_id_fields = ('name',)
        fields = ['name', 'active', 'position', 'categories', 'sites']
```

sites and categories - is a m2m field.
Export works fine, we get such CSV file with the following contents:

```
name,active,position,sites,categories
Excport CSV test,1,13,1,"19,26"
```

but when you try to import m2m field are not added. How to import data with m2m relationships?!

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/49) is an example with some code, so you can have an idea of the proper way of implementation.

Comment: This partly helped me, but I'm still working on a complete solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**django-import-export** has it's own widgets to handle models relationships:

```
    from import_export import fields, resources
    from import_export.widgets import ManyToManyWidget

    class ImportExportAdsTypeResource(resources.ModelResource):
        categories = fields.Field(widget=ManyToManyWidget(Category))
        sites = fields.Field(widget=ManyToManyWidget(Site))

        class Meta:
            model = AdType
            import_id_fields = ('name',)
            fields = ['name', 'active', 'position', 'categories', 'sites']
```

Check here for other widgets: [django-import-export Widgets](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_widgets.html#widgets)

Comment: For version `1.2.0` this worked without using `ManyToManyWidget`. Just add field in `fields` and import/export works fine.